# On click open image link to the next tab

Tags: feature-request, images

Users sometimes provide screen shot or other images at their post. We often need to open it to understand the question. Currently, when we click the image it opens in the same tab, so we lost the post (until we click backspace). I think it is odd because most of the time we need to see the image and read the description at the same time. So I would request that on click the image should open in the next tab.

```
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src=""></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The target attribute on anchors is relatively unreliable.
Browser / user settings can completely ignore the intended target of a link.

If you want to open the link in a new tab, just open it in a new tab yourself:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> click it.
- Middle mouse click it.
- Rightclick it -> "Open in new tab"
- Etc...

Comment: Could you please explain the sentence to further? “The target attribute on anchors is relatively unreliable.Browser / user settings can completely ignore the intended target of a link.” why unreliable and how to ignore the target in chrome?:~)

Comment: @PageYe: What that means is that, even if you set a `target`, A browser can be configured to do something different.

Answer (score 2):

A website should not make the decision to open a link in a new tab/window.

See [User Experience Stack Exchange - What's Your Take on target=“_blank”?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/5397/11196) for an informative discussion on the subject.